# auto ninja error

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I am trying to build Chromium and was following the steps as shown in the website but while executing the cmds below:

```
$ autoninja -C out/Default chrome
$ autoninja -C out/Default chrome/test:unit_tests
```

I obtained this error, I tried all the possible ways to get rid of this error but was unsuccessful.

I would need help in clearing this error, please?

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[265/43203] ACTION //third_party/blink/renderer/platform:color_data(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)

FAILED: gen/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/color_data.cc  python
../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts/run_with_pythonpath.py
-I ../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts -I ../../third_party -I ../../tools ../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts/gperf.py gperf --key-positions=\* -D -s 2
../../third_party/blink/renderer/platform/color_data.gperf
--output-file=gen/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/color_data.cc

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts/gperf.py", line
89, in <module>
    main()    File "../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts/gperf.py", line 86, in
main
    generate_gperf(gperf_path, open(infile).read(), gperf_args))    File "../../third_party/blink/renderer/build/scripts/gperf.py", line
46, in generate_gperf
    127, cmd, output='Command not found.')

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gperf', '--key-positions=*',
'-D', '-s', '2']' returned non-zero exit status 127 
[272/43203] 

CXX obj/mojo/core/impl_for_embedder/core.o 

ninja: build stopped:

 subcommand failed.
```